# C# array get last item from split in one line

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I know that this works to get the first item of an array

```
string aString = @"hello/all\this\is/a\test";
string firstItemOfSplit = aString.Split(new char[] {'\\', '/'})[0];
//firstItemOfSplit = hello
```

is there a way to get the last item? Something like

```
string aString = @"hello/all\this\is/a\test";
string lastItemOfSplit = aString.Split(new char[] {'\\', '/'})[index.last];
//lastItemOfSplit = test
```

Comment: btw, a cleaner way of calling split would be `aString.Split('\\', '/')`.

Comment: or `aString.Split(@"\/".ToCharArray ())`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use IEnumerable.Last() extension method from  System.Linq.

```
string lastItemOfSplit = aString.Split(new char[] {@"\"[0], "/"[0]}).Last();
```

Comment: Linq just gets better and better +1

Answer (score 8):

Like by using the [IEnumerable.Last()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775.aspx) extension method?  Include `System.Linq` and you'll have it.

Answer (score 8):

You could always use LINQ:

```
string lastItem = aString.Split(...).Last();
```

Note that [`Enumerable.Last()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775.aspx) *is* [optimized when working on an `IList<T>`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/29/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-11-first-single-last-and-the-ordefault-versions.aspx) and you're not applying a predicate - so it's not even going to walk over the sequence to find the last one. (Not that it's likely to be an issue anyway.)

Answer (score 3):

If you can use Linq:

```
string aString = @"hello/all\this\is/a\test";
string lastItemOfSplit = aString.Split("\/".ToCharArray ()).Last();
```

Here is a more GC-friendly version that doesn't require linq.

```
string aString = @"hello/all\this\is/a\test";
string lastItemOfSplit = 
   aString.Substring(aString.LastIndexOfAny(@"\/".ToCharArray ()) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

With .NET Core 3.0 (and .NET Standard 2.1) (C# 8) you can use Index type ([`Documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges)):

```
string lastValue = aString.Split(new char[] { '\\', '/' })[^1];
```

Answer (score 0):

this one i tried and it worked.

```
  string LastItem= (@"hello/all\this\is/a\test").Split(new char[] {@"\"[0], "/"[0]}).Last();
  Console.WriteLine(LastItem);
```